# increase TableView height based on cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I need to increase `UITableView` height based on `UITableViewCell` content size.
I'm using Custom Google Auto Complete. I have an `UITextField`. When I enter a letter in that `UITextField` it will call `shouldChangeCharactersIn` range delegate method.

Inside that method I will send dynamic request to Google AutoComplete API to get predictions result.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > 0
    {

    let newLength = (textField.text?.characters.count)! + string.characters.count - range.length
    let enteredString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with:string)

    if newLength == 0 {
        tableView.isHidden = true
    }

    if newLength > 0
    {
        address.removeAll()
        self.tableView.isHidden = false

        GetMethod("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=\(enteredString)&key=MYAPIKEY", completion: { (resultDict) in

            let resultArray = resultDict.object(forKey: "predictions")! as! NSArray

            print(resultArray.count)

            for temp in resultArray

            {
                 let newtemp = temp as! NSDictionary
                 let tempAdd = newtemp.value(forKey:"description") as! String
                let placeId = newtemp.value(forKey:"place_id") as! String
                var dict = [String : AnyObject]()
                dict["address"] = tempAdd as AnyObject?
                dict["latlong"] = placeId as AnyObject?
                self.address.append(dict as AnyObject)
                 print(newtemp.value(forKey:"description"))
                 print(self.address.count)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        })
      }
    return true
}
```

After I will store all address to Address array dynamically, I need to increase `UITableView` height based on that incoming address content.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    if cell == nil
    {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    let addresstoDisp  = address[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let name = addresstoDisp.value(forKey: "address")
    cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    cell?.textLabel?.text = name as! String

    return cell!
}
```

`UITableViewCell` height is increasing perfectly. Also I need to increase tableView height.

Comment: Why you want to increase table view height? Let table view cover all your page and design everything inside it, it will scroll automatically.

Comment: I have google maps in self.view and a textField on the top of map. If I have only one cell in tableview then I don't want the table view to cover full view controller.

Comment: Use this in viewDidLoad, self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

Comment: It creates a UIView in tableview footer and hides the map. If I set transparent color to that view then the map is not click/draggable.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add these lines after your cells are created. Because it returns 0 height in viewDidLoad()

```
 var frame = tableView.frame
 frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height
 tableView.frame = frame
```

**UPDATE**

```
//After Tableviews data source values are assigned
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tableView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```

Comment: @DilipTiwari Are you using auto layout?

Comment: yes,now i resolved my issue by taking the height constraints nd added this line before returning cell:- "tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
"

Comment: Thanks it helped me, but in my case i am using height constraint for tableview , so i am increasing tableview height constraint as tblViewHeightConstraint.constant = tblView.contentSize.height.

Comment: @DilipTiwari How to access tableViewHeightConstraint in swift file. I am new to ios development. Any clue ?

Comment: @GauravArora you should create tableViewHeightConstraint with type of NSLayoutConstraint

Answer (score 6):

The below code worked for me with UITableViewCell who has AutomaticDimension.

> 1. Create an outlet for tableViewHeight.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
var tableViewHeight: CGFloat = 0  // Dynamically calcualted height of TableView.
```

> 2. For the dynamic height of the cell, I used the below code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.estimatedRowHeight
}
```

> 3. For height of the TableView, with dynamic heights of the TableView Cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(cell.frame.size.height, self.tableViewHeight)
    self.tableViewHeight += cell.frame.size.height
    tableViewBillsHeight.constant = self.tableViewHeight
}
```

**Explanation:**

After the TableView cell is created, we fetch the frame height of the cell that is about to Display and add the height of the cell to the main TableView.

Answer (score 2):

In your `viewDidLoad` write:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    myTable.reloadData()
    myTable.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Now override the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method to give the tableview explicit height constraint:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    myTable.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:
    myTable.contentSize.height).isActive = true
}
```

This makes sure that the tableview is loaded and any constraints related layout adjustments are done.

Answer (score 1):

Without setting and resetting a height constraint you can resize a table view based on its content like so:

```
class DynamicHeightTableView: UITableView {
  override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return contentSize
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with UITableViewCell who has AutomaticDimension? I tried did not work

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with scroll view that must increase height when table view cells are loaded and also table view shouldn't be scrollable as it should display all cells (scroll is handled by scroll view). Anyway, you should use KeyValueObserver. First you create outlet for height constraint:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then you add observation for table view:

```
 private var tableViewKVO: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

After that, just add table view to observation and change height constraint size as your content size changes.

```
 self.tableViewKVO = tableView.observe(\.contentSize, changeHandler: { [weak self] (tableView, _) in
        self?.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what works for me, very simple straight forward solution:

Create a new UIElement of the TableView height constraint and connecting it to the view

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then add the following wherever you are creating your cells, in my case I was using RxSwift

```
 if self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > 0 {
            //gets total number of rows
            let rows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
            //Get cell desired height
            var cellHeight = 60
            self.tableViewHeightConst.constant = CGFloat(rows * cellHeight)
        }
```

this should do the trick.