# UITableView showing only one cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` with multiple data cells but when is loadaded just one cell is showed. To test, I've added 4 strings in array.

```
class LoadingDataViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewDataLoading: UITableView!
    var dados = ["Vendas","Produtos","Pessoas","Animais"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("View did load")
        tableViewDataLoading.delegate = self
        tableViewDataLoading.dataSource = self
        tableViewDataLoading.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        tableViewDataLoading.layer.borderColor = UIColor.vorazColor.cgColor
        tableViewDataLoading.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        tableViewDataLoading.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dados.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellLoadingData") as! CellDataLoading
        print("CELL: \(indexPath.row) - \(dados[indexPath.row])")
        cell.lblDado.text = dados[indexPath.row]
        cell.indicatorDado.startAnimating()
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: UITableViewAutomaticDimension))
        let label = UILabel(frame: headerView.frame)
        label.center = headerView.center
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.vorazColor
        label.text = "Baixando dados..."
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        return headerView
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let buttonCancel = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: UITableViewAutomaticDimension))
        buttonCancel.backgroundColor = UIColor.vorazColor
        buttonCancel.setTitle("Cancelar", for: .normal)
        buttonCancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelar), for: .touchUpInside)
        return buttonCancel
    }
    
    @objc func cancelar(_ sender : UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
    }
    
}

class CellDataLoading : UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imgCheckDado: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var indicatorDado: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDado: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
}
```

The result:

[image]

Storyboard:

[image]

Obs.: The label of header view is not showed and this ViewController is presented like popup.

Comment: I see the separator line near the bottom of that view.  Is that something you can scroll down to view the other 3 cells?  Maybe you need to make the height of your cell much more narrow?

Comment: Yes, you alright.. but why not happens automatically?

Comment: I fixed height, but the Table use more space that need. https://imgur.com/a/nMzWNnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I like Dhaval D approach more than what I did in a recent project, mainly the observer on table content size, here is what I did under a time crunch.

Table view is in a container view.  Container view has a height constraint on it. Table view is pinned on all sides to Container view. Anytime tableview data changes, I called

```
func updateTableSize() {

        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        var tableFrame = tableView.frame
        tableFrame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height
        tableFrame.size.width = tableView.contentSize.width 
        tableView.frame = tableFrame
        heightConstraint.constant = tableFrame.size.height
    }
```

Comment: This solves my problem, but the little white space appears between footer and border: https://imgur.com/a/clZOWrv

Comment: @Augusto. Have you tried Debug View Hierarchy to see where that white space is coming from ?  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple numbers that matter here.  Checkout a screenshot from my project:
[image: My Table View]

I gave this table an explicit row height, and at the bottom, I gave the table a fixed height via AutoLayoutw.

These numbers are probably not right for your project, but if you adjust the height of your cells I think you'll see much better results.

Comment: I fixed the row height and works, but the height of `TableView` keeping more that needs.

Comment: You can shrink your table view by clicking on the table view and then adding a height constraint.

Comment: The height depends of quantity of itens

Comment: Other people [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760815/set-tableview-height-by-the-number-or-rows) [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001944/uitableview-height-based-on-number-of-cells/13001995) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094672/increase-tableview-height-based-on-cells/41117658) [problem](https://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2014/02/resize-uitableview-height-with-auto-layout/) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240761/adjust-uitableview-height-dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

Set height constraint to your UITableView and use it like below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableViewDataLoading.delegate = self
    tableViewDataLoading.dataSource = self
    tableViewDataLoading.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    tableViewDataLoading.layer.borderColor = UIColor.vorazColor.cgColor
    tableViewDataLoading.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    tableViewDataLoading.clipsToBounds = true

    // For dynamic height of cells if you need that otherwise only write `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
    tableViewDataLoading.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0
    tableViewDataLoading.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableViewDataLoading.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableViewDataLoading.contentSize.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.updateConstraints()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // For static height
    // return 40 // Here you can set your desired height 

    // For dynamic cell height 
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: The height problem is about whole UITableView, not for each row.

Comment: From your screen shot I can not tell constraints are proper or not, have you set height and width constraints or top, bottom, leading and trailing for your UITableView?

Comment: I have update my answer to set dynamic height of UITableView based on its content.

Comment: Change nothing.

Comment: Have you set height, leading, trailing and centre vertically or top constraints as per your needs?

Comment: Yes, but in other cases that I need this, the size is automatically changed.

Comment: Then you have to try `active=true` or `active=false` for some constraint in particular cases when you don't need them.